# C-like forward declaration in python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

How would I properly do the following in python?

```
class AnyType:
    def __init__(self, Type:Union[PrimitiveType, ComplexType]):
        self.Type = Type

class PrimitiveType(AnyType):
    def __init__(self, Type):
        super().__init__(Type)

class NestedType(AnyType):
    def __init__(self, Type):
        super().__init__(Type)
```

> NameError: name 'PrimitiveType' is not defined

I know in C there is a forward declaration but how do I prevent the following circular reference in python?

Comment: A class usually should not depend on the existence of any particular subclasses. What's your use case for this?

Comment: @chepner a bit more detail is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74417988/type-annotation-on-type-hierarchy?noredirect=1#comment131372739_74417988

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Why would a type require a subtype in order to instantiate it?

Comment: @chepner it probably wouldn't or shouldn't, to be honest this is my first time trying to design a sort of type hierarchy like this so sort of playing around with it a bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/) describing such feature. If you use python3.7+ you can add `from __future__ import annotations` at the beginning and it should work. In other case, using string fixes the problem

```
class AnyType:
    def __init__(self, Type:Union["PrimitiveType", "ComplexType"]):
        self.Type = Type
```